# i want to get key value of id and name using filter in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am create category auto populated drop down. In which I want to get id and name as key value using array filter how can I get in react JS. Below I am sharing my code.I am using there array filter how can I get id values and names as 2 dimensional array .

```
const handleCheck = (event) => {
      var checkList = [...check];
      console.log("fffd", event)
      if (check.includes(event.name)) {
         let arr = check.filter(item => item !== event.name &&  item !== event.list_category)
         console.log("arrarrarr",arr)
         setCheck(arr);

      }
      else {
         checkList = [...check, event.name, event.list_category];
         console.log("arrarrarrcheckList",checkList)
         setCheck(checkList);
      }

   };


   /**on Submit  */
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(check.length>0){
         console.log("bddhcjhecked",check)
           //console.log("setSelectedCategories..............", setSelectedCategories)
      props.setSelectedCategories(check)
      history.push('/CheckList')
     // console.log('kk...................', check) 
      }
      else{
         toast.error("Select atleast one category")
         return false
      }
   
      
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what are you trying to do?

Comment: from array filter how can I get key value.

Comment: is key present in `check` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per I have understood your question, you are trying to get the value of `id` and `name` from `check` array after performing `filter` on it. To do that you can chain `map` method on `filter` as filter will return array. Something like this:

```js
let arr = check.filter(item => item !== event.name &&  item !== event.list_category).map(item => [item.id, item.name])
```